# Arduino Mega and LP621024D70LL

Tags: arduino-mega, sram

I'm intending to try a LP621024D70LL (128 KB SRAM memory, 32 pins) on an Arduino Mega.

However, I now see there is no library for it ... I wonder how hard it is to access it? I can miss 32 digital pins (the Mega has enough), however, I'm a bit worried about having to write a library, especially since I do not have any gear like an oscilloscope.

Would it be easy to use the library of the more knwn 32K256 or 23LC1024 as basis? (where I also have no experience with btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's so old I can't find a datasheet for it. If you know the pinout then you know more than me at the moment. Chances are it's a standard 8-bit CPU interface.

- Writing:

Set the address on the address pins, set the data to write on the data pins, enable the chip, and pulse WR.

- Reading:

Set the address on the address pins, enable the chip, and while pulsing the OE pin read the data pins.

And no, you can't really use a serial SRAM chip library as a basis - the operation is completely different.

Comment: http://www.allcomponents.ru/pdf/amicc/lp621024d70ll.pdf

Comment: Thanks ... well I have the datasheet: http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/55651/AMICC/LP621024D-70LL/133/1/LP621024D-70LL.html 

Doesn't seem to complicated what you write :-) Going to give it a try ... and if I succeed I will make it public for everyone if interested. 
Didn't know it as old, but I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yep, it is as I described. It has two chip-enable pins, one has to be high and the other low to enable it (you can probably tie them both permanently enabled since you aren't sharing the bus) and just toggle the OE or WR pins.

Comment: No one much uses parallel SRAM chips any more. They are quite rare new.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation ... and I understand the 23LC1024 has less ins, but works more complicated (although with a library it isn't a problem). But besides it is a bit cheaper, the main reason is I'm just getting into electronics so 'back to the basics' is maybe not so bad after all.

Comment: This kind of chip is best used with a small MCU. Something like a 6502 or a Z80. Use it to build your own computer from discrete ICs ;)

Comment: (I also ordered a 23LC1024 so I can try both... 6502 sounds cool to (I remember it was the heart of the Commodore 64).

Comment: And many other systems too. 4 things are all you need: a 6502, some SRAM (you have), a parallel Flash chip, and some form of IO interface. Oh, and some way of getting code onto the flash chip. And there's your computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55696/discussion-between-michel-keijzers-and-majenko).